# Is there a simple way to add an url as launcher on Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, launcher, ubuntu-sdk, webapps

Right now, if one wants to gain quick access to a webpage on Ubuntu Touch devices, the best way is to create a simple webapp, using Ubuntu SDK or w/e.

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a way to add an url as a shortcut in the launcher or the app menu (even better), without actually creating an app?

Comment: Not using Touch, but you can simply hold for simulating right-click?

Comment: In Chrome there is 'send to desktop as app' function, and you can set it in windowed mode too. In menu on the right upper corner, more setting, I guess. Idk about the others. On my phone right now. Will check later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to do this, although not very userfriendly.
You can copy `/usr/share/applications/webbrowser-app.desktop` to `~/.local/share/applications`, rename it and add the url of your site like this:

```
Exec=webbrowser-app %u
```

to

```
Exec=webbrowser-app %u http://askubuntu.com
```

You can also change the `Name` and the `Icon` of the shortcut.

Comment: i think that should be good enough. will test it.